# TypeError: undefined is not an object error

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I have this code, which is throwing a TypeError. I can't find what the problem is.

**Code**

```
/ Topic Banners - swap out mobile ads
if ($('#advertisment-main').length){
    if (matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
    var topicBannerName = $('.topic-banner[src*="mobile"]').attr('src').replace('mobile.jpg','');
    $('.topic-banner').attr('src', topicBannerName + 'tablet.jpg');
    } else{
        var topicBannerName = $('.topic-banner[src*="tablet"]').attr('src').replace('tablet.jpg','');
        $('.topic-banner').attr('src', topicBannerName + 'mobile.jpg');
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$('.topic-banner[src*="tablet"]').attr("src").replace')
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: Yup jQuery is included, everything else on the page works.

Comment: There must be no matching elements for selector `$('.topic-banner[src*="tablet"]')`

Comment: Than please post your source code on jsfiddle so we can take a closer look at it

Comment: @nikhil I think you're onto something

Comment: seems like, you need to utilize jquery each function for doing this, as you are using class selector.

Comment: @nikhil Or there is a matching element, but `.attr('src')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @gfullam - That is not possible as the selector is an src attribute selector itself.

Comment: @nikhil You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your selector `$('.topic-banner[src*="tablet"]')` doesn't match any elements. Make sure that the selector and HTML code is correct.

Comment: Second statement is incorrect. It is a `src` attribute selector.